# Windows Service - migration to 64-bit. Steps in order to achieve '64-bit benefits'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services, 64-bit

I have my own old Windows Service (.Net 3.5) which was running at 32-bit windows. Now we have a x64 Windows Server 2012, and would like to migrate this Service.

My question is : should I do something special with this Windows Service in order to achieve in it "all benefits" of 64-bit framework ? I mean - should I set some options during building/compiling it in Visual Studio 2010 (project/solution properties). Or something else ? Or I don't need to do anything - it will use 64-bit framework by itself, no matter how it's build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the build target:

- if the platform target is `x86`, it will always run as a 32-bit executable (or not at all)
- if the platform target is `x64`, it will always run as a 64-bit executable (or not at all)
- if the platform target is `Any CPU` **without** "Prefer 32-bit" enabled, it will run as 64-bit where possible, else 32-bit
- if the platform target is `Any CPU` **with** "Prefer 32-bit" enabled, it will run as 32-bit where possible, else 64-bit

You can use `Environment.Is64BitProcess` to check how your application is running (or just look in task manager).

For your scenario, `Any CPU` **without** "Prefer 32-bit" would seem the correct choice.

Answer (score 2):

Since this started as a 3.5 project, no, you probably don't have to change *anything*.  The setting that matters is Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target setting.  The default in older versions of Visual Studio was AnyCPU.  Which does what it says, it runs on any CPU so you get a 64-bit process on a 64-bit operating system.  If it is "x86" (or the Prefer 32-bit checkbox is checked) then you *force* it to run in 32-bit mode.

It doesn't actually matter much btw, the only benefit of a 64-bit process is that it can consume a lot more memory.  Well past the 2 gigabyte that a 32-bit process is restricted to.  A service should never have that kind of impact on a machine.

Comment: There are lots of other differences - a completely different JIT and GC, for example. And I quietly hold my hand up to say "my services use a **lot** more memory than that... for good reasons". Heck, SQL Server is "a service" - you certainly wouldn't limit that to 2GB/3GB.

Comment: Erm, they still jit code and collect garbage, that's not any different.  Not so sure that your SE dbase machines are representative :)

Comment: There are quite a few cases where the differences in how the jitter works, differences in how well a problem does or doesn't suit 64-bit arithmetic, and other differences make 64-bit a strong win. I've one piece of code that runs about 6-8 times faster on 64-bit than 32-bit, sometimes more; now it was optimised all the way through for 64-bit use so it's not a representative example, but it does stand as the exception that proves. That said, the opposite is very often true too; the smaller memory use can make 32-bit code faster than 64-bit, even when run on 64-bit.